# What is the significance of docker bridge address in kubernetes cluster hosted on AKS?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks

I would like to understand the purpose of Docker bridge address in Kubernetes cluster. Is it related to container to container communication or is it something else.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker bridge network address represents the default docker0 bridge network address present in all Docker installations.

While docker0 bridge is not used by AKS clusters or the pods themselves, you must set this address to continue to support scenarios such as docker build within the AKS cluster.

It is required to select a CIDR for the Docker bridge network address because otherwise Docker will pick a subnet automatically which could conflict with other CIDRs.

This network 172.17.0.0/16 is default when you installed docker. Please refer below link for more explanation. https://github.com/docker/for-aws/issues/117  Because docker choose first available network and most of the time end up choosing 172.17.0.0/16 hence this route is added locally towards docker0 bridge

Regards,

Vinoth